# Given that $f$ and $g$ are homomorphisms, the implication that $f \odot g$ is also a homomorphism implies $(S, \odot)$ is entropic - why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

Context: Seth Warner's "Modern Algebra" (1965), exercise $13.13$. Ongoing self-study.

> Let $(S, \odot)$ and $(T, \otimes)$ be closed algebraic structures with one operation. Let $(S, \odot)$ be such that if $f: T \to S$ and $g: T \to S$ are homomorphisms, then $f \odot g$ is also a homomorphism. Then $(S, \odot)$ is necessarily an entropic structure.

EDIT: After a comment by Eric Wofsey, I look more closely and it should say:

> Let $(S, \odot)$ be a closed algebraic structures with one operation. Let $(S, \odot)$ be such that if $(T, \otimes)$ is any arbitrary closed algebraic structure with one operation, and $f: T \to S$ and $g: T \to S$ are homomorphisms, then $f \odot g$ is also a homomorphism.

In the above:

- $f \odot g$ denotes the pointwise operation induced by $\odot$, that is: $(f \odot g) (x) = f(x) \odot g(x)$.
- By "entropic", I mean that  $(w \odot x) \odot (y \odot z) = (w \odot y) \odot (x \odot z)$ for all $w, x, y, z \in S$.
- a "closed algebraic structure" is simply a "magma".

I have worked through the straightforward algebra as follows:

$(f (a) \odot f (b)) \odot (g (a) \odot g (b))$

$=(f (a \otimes b) )\odot (g (a \otimes b) )$ (as $f$ and $g$ are both homomorphisms)

$= (f \odot g) (a \otimes b)$ (by definition of pointwise operation)

$= (f \odot g) (a) \odot (f \odot g) (b)$ (as $f \odot g$ is a homomorphism)

$= (f (a) \odot g (a) \odot (f (b) \odot g (b))$ (by definition of pointwise operation)

Thus we have:
$$(f (a) \odot f (b)) \odot (g (a) \odot g (b)) = (f (a) \odot g (a) \odot (f (b) \odot g (b))$$

and thus $(S, \odot)$ exhibits the symptoms of being entropic.

But this only demonstrates that elements in the image set of $f$ and $g$ have the property that make $\odot$ entropic. From the above analysis, it is entirely possible that there exist $w, x, y, z \in S$ which are *not* the images of homomorphisms, which do not have the property that $(w \odot x) \odot (y \odot z) = (w \odot y) \odot (x \odot z)$.

How do I rescue this proof?

(Note of course that based on the above, the converse is trivial to prove: that if $(S, \odot)$ is entropic, then for homomorphisms $f$ and $g$ from $T$ to $S$ it follows that $f \odot g$ is also necessarily a homomorphism.)

Please feel free to add whatever tags are necessary for this question -- I haven't managed to find any more than the one.

Comment: What is your definition of "entropic"?  That the identity $(w \odot x) \odot (y \odot z) = (w \odot y) \odot (x \odot z)$ holds?

Comment: In any case this seems to simply not be true as written.  For instance, $T$ could be such that there are *no* homomorphisms $T\to S$ at all, and then the hypothesis holds vacuously.  Maybe the hypothesis is supposed to be that $S$ has this property for *all* $T$?

Comment: Or, for instance, if $T$ is empty, then there is only one homomorphism $T\to S$ no matter what $S$ is and the hypothesis always holds.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is indeed the definition.. I did not include that definition because I understand that one is not supposed to do so on MSE. At least, when in the past I have asked on comments on various questions what is meant by whatever concept, I have been informed "if you need to ask what it means, then you're not qualified to answer the question, so including the explanation / definition is not necessary or desirable." I will add the definition to the question.

Comment: My suggestion is that $f$ and $g$ probably need to be epimorphisms (that is, surjective, that is, "onto" homomorphisms). If this is the case, then it would be a seriously uncharacteristic mistake in (by what I can tell) an extremely high quality work.

Comment: What does “closed” mean in this context? I.e., can we assume anything stronger than $S,T$ being magmas?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, I used "closed algebraic structure" a) because that is the terminology used by Warner, and b) I thought it was clearer than "magma" because some people might not know what "magma" means. I'll never get the hang of the protocols of this site. Question edited to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true as written.  For instance, if $T$ is empty, then no matter what $S$ is, there is only one map $T\to S$, and so the hypothesis is always trivially true, regardless of whether $S$ is entropic.  Or, if $T$ is a singleton and $S$ has no idempotent elements, there are no homomorphisms $T\to S$, so the hypothesis holds vacuously, but $S$ does not have to be entropic (for instance, it could be the free magma on one element).

I would guess that the statement was intended to require that the hypothesis hold for *all* $T$, rather than just one fixed $T$.  In that case, you can prove it by taking $T$ to be the free magma on two generators $a$ and $b$.  Then for any $w,x,y,z\in S$, by the universal property of $T$ there exists a homomorphism $f:T\to S$ sending $a$ and $b$ to $w$ and $x$ and a homomorphism $g:T\to S$ sending $a$ and $b$ to $y$ and $z$.  Combined with your argument this shows that $S$ must be entropic.

Comment: Yes, having re-read it, that does seem to be the intent of the question. I now need to go away and study what the free magma on two generators is. Thx.